# Recover a unit vector from a unit normal and a linear transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, normed-spaces

The unit vector in the direction of $A\vec{u}$ where $A$ is an invertible ${m}\times{m}$ matrix and $n,u$ are $m\times1$ vectors  is $$\vec{n} = \frac{A\vec{u}}{\|A\vec{u}\|}$$
how can I recover the unit vector in the direction of $\vec{u}$ if what I actually have is $A$ and $\vec{n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is invertible, we have
$$
\hat u = \frac{A^{-1}\vec n}{\|A^{-1}\vec n\|}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! Yes A is invertible. Quick check before I accept: is this exactly "u" or the unit vector in the direction of u?

Comment: I ask because what I really need is u. But I may be able to make the unit vector work if I can't get that. Sorry for the trouble! I have some linear algebra knowledge gaps.

Comment: @Cogicero this is the unit vector in the direction of $\vec u$, sorry for not clarifying

Comment: @Cogicero Because we only have the direction (and not the length) of the output, we have no way of recovering the length of the input.

Comment: Got it, thank you!